# XmlDocument formatting with XmlCDataSection

Tags: c#, xmldocument

When I add a XmlCDataSection to my XmlDocument it messes up my Xml-formatting.

```
string newFileName = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
XmlCDataSection c = xd.CreateCDataSection("mycdatacontent");
xd.ChildNodes[0].AppendChild(c);
xd.Save(newFileName);
```

The output looks like this:

```
<item>
  <name>wrench</name><![CDATA[mycdatacontent]]></item>
```

But it should look like this:

```
<item>
  <name>wrench</name>
  <![CDATA[mycdatacontent]]>
</item>
```

How can I change it so that the output looks how i expect it to be?
The CDataSection need to be in a seperate line.

Comment: Try `XmlWriter` and `XmlWriterSettings.Indent`. There is an example in documentation for [XmlDocument.LoadXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml). But wht you want is actually not a standard way. This CDATA section is not encapsulated in its own element. Maybe there is no way to do it, or you have to also insert some `XmlWhitespace` manually.

Comment: `XmlWriterSettings.Indent` hasn't changed the format of the file. The only difference now is, that it has automatically created the XML header.